# Firebase Cloud Firestore "Request/response" documentation

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, documentation

Most of "bigger" project I was working with was using REST API for Frontend->Backend communication. I was using Firebase Cloud Firestore for some small (one-day/hackathon) projects. Now I'm thinking about using Firestore for some bigger project but I'm not sure if this will work.

For "standard", REST api project I had Swagger documentation, where each developer could see list of all endpoints with request/response data structures. How does it work with Firestore? Can I create similar documentation for developers to check data structure, so they will know what can they add and what should they read? Or maybe there is another way?

I'm thinking, maybe there is no tool for this kind of documentation because frontend data structures are defining database structure? But what if I am connecting database from two or more platform (ex. web, mobile and cloud functions)? How can I synchronize knowledge about data structures between all the developers?

I was looking for some answers but couldn't find anything useful expect advice to manually maintain some documentation. How does it work in your projects? Is there some automation? Manually written documentation? Or no documentation - everything "in code"?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your concerns, but unfortunately, there is no such tool available for Cloud Firestore to generate the documentation for database structure as Swagger.

I believe you can do it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

From
[Generating Swagger Docs in Firebase Cloud Functions project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573560/generating-swagger-docs-in-firebase-cloud-functions-project)

> I'm using express and nodejs in my Firebase Function implementations, and for me, Swagger doc generation can be implemented via the following libraries:.
>
> https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express
>
> https://github.com/Surnet/swagger-jsdoc
>
> You can find other libraries at:
> https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/open-source-integrations

In addition to the responses there, the following service allows you to access Firestore metadata, click the explorer tab, looks promising for your use case https://aapi.io/api-directory/Google_CloudFirestore_GoogleCloudFirestoreAPI_v1beta1 though not necessarily more so than the links above.